# JMeter - How to login with "x" different users parallely and each user does as PUT request "y" times

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter 3.1 to perform a load test. I need to Login with different users and each user have to create an entry multiple times. Below is the scenario i am trying to do.

Step 1. Login to application.
Step 2. Fetch the template name.
Step 3. Use template name and create an entry for that template.

For the above steps, i want to run Step 1, Step 2 and Step 3 each run sequentially and Step 3 should execute 10 times. It should execute like Step1, Step 2, Step 3(1), Step 3(2).......,Step 3(10).

Like this i want 100 different users login in at a time and perform the three steps as expected above.

Answer (score 0):

1. To execute your step 3 10 times just put the associated request under a [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set Loop Count to "10"
2. If you need to execute some sampler in parallel, i.e. at exactly the same moment in time, add [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) as a child of this sampler.

   [image: JMeter Loop Controller Synchronizing Timer]